# Android Videoview giving isPlaying() false

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

**-** I have two activities, suppose Activity A and Activity B.

**-** My aim here is to have a function that will record a video and save it. Then once its done, we play it and printing at `Logcat` that its playing.

**-** We are using `VideoView` to play the video, and `isPlaying()` method to get the confirmation that its playing.

**-** Now in Activity A we are able to get **true** for isPlaying() but we get **false** for the same in Activity B. Even if we can see the video play, still we get **false** for `isPlaying()` while the video is very much playing.

**The code that works in Activity A but not in Activity B:**

```
final Dialog nagDialog = new Dialog(RMMGuessMime.this,android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);

        View vx = View.inflate(RMMGuessMime.this,R.layout.pop_video,null);
        nagDialog.setContentView(vx);
        nagDialog.setCancelable(true);

        final VideoView vVideo = (VideoView)vx.findViewById(R.id.vv);
        vVideo.setVideoPath(videoUri.getPath());




            Thread audioPlay = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    vVideo.start();
                    System.out.println("Vv started :"+vVideo.isPlaying());


                    while(vVideo.isPlaying()){

                        //------------------------------ Here i want my Sysout or Log to be printed as true...but instead i am getting false...

                    }
                }
            });

            audioPlay.start();
```

I have done and tried everything possible to set this right but its not working....... please help me out...

Comment: See if the context in Activity B, for the view is right.

Comment: As Guilherme said, it's probably this: View vx = View.inflate(RMMGuessMime.this,R.layout.pop_video,null);

Comment: there is no problem in the view